# Zend framework 2 create simple program with example

Tags: zend-framework2

I am in new for zend framework 2.
I want simple program for eg 5 values give input add and view the output.
Index.html and indexcontroller.php both file one small example give me.

Answer (score 1):

You can read documentation and create simple application
http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/overview.html

Or you can get skeleton application
http://framework.zend.com/downloads/skeleton-app

Comment: thank you for your answer. But here only Database connectivity in first example. So i want simply front end only to give. then i can pick easiy in DB connectivity

Comment: It's a user guide, it's has informations about controllers/models/views. You need see next pages on this tutorial. You can get skeleton application from this page http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html and you can see ready controller and view.